# Laravel Ladp Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, windows-services, windows-server-2019

I am trying to use ladp to authenticate my laravel web app but I am getting this error  `Adldap\Auth\BindException Can't contact LDAP server` at line `throw (new BindException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e))` in adldap2\adldap2\src\Auth\Guard.php:107

I have configured active directory services on the windows server and have added the ip address of the server to my ladp.php file. Can someone please help?

Comment: Sounds like a network issue. Are you running this code on your domain controller, or from a different computer? Are you able to use AD Users and Computers?

Comment: Different computer

Comment: Can you use AD Users and Computers on that computer to browse the domain?